# Finding the context for Glide Android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-glide

I'm trying to show pictures in a GridView. This Grid View is filled by an Adapter.
I always had the problem that the application is very laggy when it inflates a new card. After some searching in the internet i found Glide, which could maybe help to make the performance better.

Now I'm stuck because i can't imagine what context i should pass in at Glide.with(...):

```
Glide.with(**CONTEXT**).load(sights.get(i).mImageRessourceID).into(sightViewHolder.sightPhoto);
```

To build the Cards i use: MainActivity -> Fragment -> Adapter.

That's the code from the adapter:

```
public class SightCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SightCardAdapter.SightViewHolder> {


public static class SightViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView sightName;
    ImageView sightPhoto;

    SightViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        sightName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sight_name);
        sightPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sight_photo);
    }
}

List<Sight> sights;

SightCardAdapter(List<Sight> sights) {
    this.sights = sights;
}


@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public SightViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    SightViewHolder pvh = new SightViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SightViewHolder sightViewHolder, int i) {
    sightViewHolder.sightName.setText(sights.get(i).mName);
    //sightViewHolder.sightPhoto.setImageResource(sights.get(i).mImageRessourceID);
    Glide.with().load(sights.get(i).mImageRessourceID).into(sightViewHolder.sightPhoto); // missing context
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sights.size();
}
```

}

Can anybody please give me some hint? I can't image what I should pass in.

PS: Additionally if anybody has some tipps how to make my code more efficient i would be very grateful :)

Comment: Pass context to adapter - SightViewHolder(View itemView, Context context)

Comment: in the same way as you passed it to `LayoutInflater.from` ... hint: which method of which class did you use it?

Comment: pass context as a parameter refer Sataym's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43518232/3578677

Comment: There is no need to pass Context to SightViewHolder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While passing data to the Adapter also pass a parameter Context. If you are calling your Adapter from Fragment that is child of MainActivity, simply pass getApplicationContext() as context to your Adapter.

```
SightCardAdapter(Context context,List<Sight> sights) {
     this.sights = sights;
     this.context=context;
}

while calling from Fragment.
SightCardAdapter(getApplicationContext(),sights);
```

Comment: I already tried this solution. Looks like:
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(sights.get(i).mImageRessourceID).into(sightViewHolder.sightPhoto);
But Android Studio says cannot resolve method :S

Comment: Glide.with(getApplicationContext()) you cant use getApplicationContext() inside adapter. From Fragment send this context to your Adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `Context` from Any [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) Object.

```
Glide.with(sightViewHolder.sightPhoto.getContext()).load(sights.get(i).mImageRessourceID).into(sightViewHolder.sightPhoto);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass Context when you create object for Adapter., Changed code below

```
public class SightCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SightCardAdapter.SightViewHolder> {


public static class SightViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView sightName;
    ImageView sightPhoto;


    SightViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        sightName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sight_name);
        sightPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sight_photo);

    }
}
Context context;
List<Sight> sights;

SightCardAdapter(List<Sight> sights,Context context) {
    this.sights = sights;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public SightViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    SightViewHolder pvh = new SightViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SightViewHolder sightViewHolder, int i) {
    sightViewHolder.sightName.setText(sights.get(i).mName);
    //sightViewHolder.sightPhoto.setImageResource(sights.get(i).mImageRessourceID);
    Glide.with(context).load(sights.get(i).mImageRessourceID).into(sightViewHolder.sightPhoto); // missing context
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sights.size();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your context in adapter like this

```
Private Context mContext;
SightCardAdapter(List<Sight> sights,Context mContext) {
    this.sights = sights;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

Glide.with(mContext).load("url").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

for efficient use..

```
private RequestManager glideManager;  

public MyAdater(Context context, Object activityOrFragment){
     if (object instanceof Fragment) {
         glideManager = Glide.with((Fragment) object);
     } else if (object instanceof Activity) {
         glideManager = Glide.with((Activity) object);
     }
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderGeneric viewHolder, int position) {
   glideManager
         .load(item.getResizedImageUrl())
         .placeholder(R.drawable.emptystates_card_bg_none)
         .fitCenter()
         .into(ivGoods);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(mContext, this);  //this -> Activity or Fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Context context;//declare this globle

SightCardAdapter(Context context, List<Sight> sights) {
    this.context=context;// add context in constructor of adapter class
    this.sights = sights;
}
```

Now, use `context` in `Glide` as below:

```
Glide.with(context).load(sights.get(i).mImageRessourceID).into(sightViewHolder.sightPhoto);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

Either pass context from activity while creating adapter object or get it from itemView.

```
Context context = itemView.getContext();
Pass this context to Glide.
```